# How do i set the selected item in a drop down box?

Tags: php

I have edit form where i need to set option value as `select=selected` based on database value

```
<option selected="selected" value="2">laravel</option>
```

i have following code

```
 @foreach($category_list as $data)

  <option value="{{$data->id }}" >{{$data->cat_name}}</option>

                  @endforeach
```

Now i need to compare `{{$data->id }}` with database value id `{{$single_edit_product->id}}` and set option value as  `selected="selected"`.i know i can do using ternary but i failed to do using blade template.

can anyone help me ?

**Updated**

```
@foreach($category_list as $data)

            <?php  $d1=$single_edit_product->id ;$d2=$data->id; ?>
                 <option value="{{$data->id}} " <? ($d1==$d2) ? selected='selected' ?>>{{$data->cat_name}}</option>
              @endforeach
```

Comment: The problem is that your ternary statement is not working... posting that would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your ternary statement is that it isn't compatible with blade. Instead of using short php tags `<? ?>` you should be wrapping it in blade tags `{{ }}`.

```
@foreach($category_list as $data)

    <option value="{{$data->id }}" {{ $data->id == $single_edit_product->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{$data->cat_name}}</option>

@endforeach
```

Comment: @Jeemusu.thank you for the answer.i tried but it giving me wrong category name

Comment: Try debugging it. Look at the source of your page, check the id of the option that is selected, is it correct? `echo` out the value of `$single_edit_product->id` and compare them.

Comment: iam facing one problem.can you post answe if you know.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368489/how-to-authenticate-using-socialite

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  @foreach($category_list as $data)
   @if($data->id == 'option value which need to be compared')
  <option value="{{$data->id }}" selected>{{$data->cat_name}}</option>
   @else
  <option value="{{$data->id }}">{{$data->cat_name}}</option>
   @endif   

   @endforeach
```